# android button latch behaviour

Tags: android, button, layout

I am new to android and java so please be kind - I know my approach is not correct
I want to have a state (Process running) while the button is pressed (A latch state)
What I have tried is the following in the xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me"
    android:onClick="otherClicked">
</Button>
```

then I try and handle it like so (The toast is just for debugging)

```
public void otherClicked(View v) {
   if(v.getId() == R.id.my_btn) {
      if(v.findViewById(v.getId()).isPressed() == true) {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "isPressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use onTouchListener

```
brown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.my_btn);
brown.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //down clicked
        } else if (event.getAction() == (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)) {
            //button release
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

// Example of how to define button in XML

```
<Button
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/self_destruct"
     android:onClick="selfDestruct" />
```

// Example of Activity class

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);

         setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

         final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });
     }
 }

public void selfDestruct(View view) {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "isPressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}
```

Comment: This is for clicking a button. He is inquiring about *latching* onto the button, meaning holding it down (I presume).

Answer (score 0):

For two states Android has a [toggle button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html) - please check that. Button has behaviour called only click, but toggle button has on/off states. Hope I'm not wrong for what you're expecting as an answer.